# Plotting haploNet in R - overlapping nodes

Tags: r, plot, visualization, network-analysis

I'm plotting a haploNet generated in [pegas](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pegas/pegas.pdf). Everything's working fine, except that some pies are overlapping each other (e.g. bottom right part of the first plot). Using `fast=FALSE` or setting a very high scale.ratio doesn't seem to fix the problem (see bottom plot).

Is there a way to force the branches to "fan out more"?

```
plot(net, size=attr(net, "freq"), scale.ratio = .42, 
     cex = .5, labels=F, pie = dc, lwd = .01, font=2, fast=F, legend=T)
```

[image: "normal plot]

[image: plot with scale.ratio=5.22]

Answer (score 0):

Use `replot()`. You may need to update R to access this function.